# Run python mysql client on slim python 3.6 docker image

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I have a working service running on a python:3.6-jessie image.
I am trying to reduce the size of it to speed up serverless cold starts.

I have tried the images python:3.6-alpine, python:3.6-slim-buster and python:3.6-slim-jessie.

With all of them I end up having to install many additional packages and I end up with the follwing error that I cannot fix with more packages:

```
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My current Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.6-jessie as build

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 0
ENV FLASK_APP "api/app.py"

RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
WORKDIR /opt/venv

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

FROM python:3.6-slim-jessie
COPY --from=build /opt/venv /opt/venv
WORKDIR /opt/venv
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install gcc
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install python-mysqldb

ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

RUN rm -rf configs tests draw_results env .idea .git .pytest_cache

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/opt/venv/run.sh"]
```

The relevant lines from requirements.txt:

```
mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
PyMySQL==0.9.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
SQLAlchemy==1.3.0
```

The run.sh is just my gunicorn start command.

Is there any package I can use to fix this last issue, is there some other mysql library I should be using or some other way for me to fix this. Or should I just stick to full python:3.6 images when I want a mysql client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add this line to the dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I had already tried this, but then with the python:3.6-slim-buster image, and that did not work.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I often forget to install the `*-dev` packages

Comment: Got error: Package 'libmysqlclient-dev' has no installation candidate.
Using python:3.6 image

Answer (score 22):

I'm using `python:3.7-slim` and using the following command

`RUN apt-get -y install default-libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: python:3.8-slim requires `apt-get update` first. Then the install will work.

Comment: This answer helped me.  I wanted to use `mysqlclient` with my application in a container built from `python:3.9-slim`.  However, I received errors about various dependencies.  Adding the `default-libmysqlclient-dev` package to the container build resolved those dependencies.

Comment: Make sure "all" the answers that help gets upvoted to appreciate the effort.

Comment: You're probably right.  I wanted to mention my specific circumstances  for needing this solution in case it helps someone else with the same problem find this solution, too.

Comment: I'm getting a gcc error even after this, I use python:3.8-slim

Comment: @SandeepaKariyawasam I am really sorry. I am not a python guy. I was doing python when I wrote the answer. But didn't continue with the python project. Can't exactly help you. Sorry 

Answer (score 1):

For python slim-buster (debian os) use can run this command on Dockerfile.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client
```

This worked for me.
I have used python:3.10.6-slim-buster

Answer (score 0):

Small update on the previous answers for anyone who is reading this thread in 2024.

- Installing `libmysqlclient-dev` generates an error like this:

```bash
#8 3.256 Package libmysqlclient-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
#8 3.256 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
#8 3.256 is only available from another source
#8 3.256 However the following packages replace it:
#8 3.256   libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
#8 3.256
#8 3.368 E: Package 'libmysqlclient-dev' has no installation candidate
```

You can either:

- Install `default-libmysqlclient-dev` and `libxslt-dev` with:

```bash
RUN apt update && apt install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev libxslt-dev
```

- Install `libmariadb-dev` and `libxslt-dev` with:

```bash
RUN apt update && apt install -y libmariadb-dev libxslt-dev
```

to fix the problem.